# Qt Creator doesn' t support Qwt Mingw plugin?

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

when i build qwt, and want to make it into Qt Desiner of Qt creater,, but occur a error: Expected build key "Windows msvc release full-config", got "Windows mingw debug full-config",,
this is the pic for it.
what happened?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Given the error you're trying to use a debug version of the plugin? Is that correct? Or at least ones linked against debug libraries.

Comment: @Bart: if i build a release version, it is the same error...

Comment: Ah, I missed the MSVC vs MINGW issue. So your Designer is probably built with (or relies on components built with) Visual Studio. I guess you are using MINGW to build your sources. You most likely will have to change one or the other.